# jquery addclass if image has specific alt tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images, all of which have alt tags.

I am trying to add a class to all of the images which have a certain alt tag.

So to put it in plain terms:

If image `alt` tag = "dog" then add class "canine"

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method:

```
$("img[alt='dog']").addClass("canine");
```

Answer (score 8):

or you can use

```
$("img[alt*='dog']").addClass("canine");
```

to include any image with alt *Containing* `dog`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('img[alt="dog"]').addClass("canine")
```

it's realy easy...

notetoself: type faster... ;)

Comment: Tell me about it, I'm usually a couple of minutes to late ;-)